# writing map methods without interface-java

Tags: java, dictionary

How do I write my own put, get, size, and remove methods of the Map interface in a class without actually implementing the Map interface? And how would the actual code look for each method?

Comment: extend the class you want to override and use the `@Override` annotation to mark the method you wish to override

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're saying is that you need custom functionality in  *some* of the methods of your map-like class, but you don't want to have to rewrite all the other methods, in which case I would recommend extending an implementation of `Map`, overriding `put()` , `get()`, `size()` and whatever other methods you need to customize, and leaving the rest alone

For example:

```
class MyMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
         //implement custom functionality
    }

//override what you need to override, don't what you don't 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MapLike<K, V> {

    public V put(K key, V value) {
        //implementation here
    }
}
```

Comment: look at that signature again... return type?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public class MyMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {
    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        // maybe I want to print the key first...
        System.out.println("Key = " + key);
        super.put(key, value);  // add it to the data structure by using the superclass
    }

    @Override
    public V get(K key) {
        // do something similar
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // do something similar
    }
}
```